# Creating .dll subproject in Visual Studio Code editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, project, subproject

I am going to create a `.dll` and an `.exe` using this `.dll` with `C#` and `.NET`.

How to create a `.dll` subproject in `Visual Studio` Code editor?

I develop on `Debian Linux`.

Comment: Just add class library in a project and write your logic there and build that you will get a dll in your project bin/debug folder

Comment: @M.Y.Mnu I am a novice with C#. I don't quite understand you. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @M.Y.Mnu How to "add class library in a project"?

Comment: right click on your project and add project and choose class library from tamplate

Comment: @M.Y.Mnu Where to right click? I clicked in various parts of the editor window and see no "reference option"

Comment: you have to right click to on project solution and add a project and choose class library option

Comment: Follow this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/creating-dll-using-class-library-in-net-framework/)

Comment: @M.Y.Mnu The link you gave is about Visual Studio but I have (what I assume is it's stripped down version) Visual Studio Code. And I have no "File" -> "New" -> "Project..." in the menu which is recommended to click there

Comment: I created a class library by `dotnet new classlib -n xyz` command, I can access it from the main program, but I have one `.dll` file while I want two assemblies: for the main program and for the xyz library.

Answer (score 1):

Create folders for both the main `.exe` project and for the `.dll` subproject. `.dll` subproject folder should *not* be inside the main project folder.

Then in the main project folder run

```
dotnet add . reference ../xyz/xyz.csproj
```

where `xyz` is the name of the `.dll` subproject.

After this building the main project automatically builds the subproject too. Exactly what I need.